# What is "I/O error 1785"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am getting "I/O error "1785" in my program in

> Vcl.FileCtrl.TDirectoryListBox.SetDirectory ->
>   Vcl.FileCtrl.ProcessPath

I cannot find a description in Delphi's Help for this.

Comment: I'm guessing `ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_MEDIA 1785 (0x6F9) The disk media is not recognized. It may not be formatted.` may be it.

Comment: From the help file: *All errors other than I/O errors and  fatal errors are reported with the error codes returned by the operating system.* Since all of the listed I/O errors are in the 100..106 range, and the fatal errors are in 200..232, it stands to reason that this is an OS error, and `SysErrorMessage(1785)` would give you a description of the error (which is as @Joachim has said).

Comment: @KenWhite That should be an answer, mine was just a guess from the code combined with IO-error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help file:

> All errors other than I/O errors and  fatal errors are reported with the error codes returned by the operating system.

As all of the listed I/O errors are in the `100..106` range, and the fatal errors are all in `200..232`, it stands to reason that this is an OS error, and `SysErrorMessage(1785)` would give you a description of the error:

> The disk media is not recognized. It may not be formatted.

The actual error is `ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_MEDIA` (thanks to @JoachimIsaksson for looking it up so I didn't have to do so).

Comment: Man! Why don't they call it ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_MEDIA instead of 1785?

Comment: @Beno: Because the error is 1785, and the computer has no idea what the *human-readable* constant ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_MEDIA means. :-) In fact, the computer knows nothing except that a function returned the value 1785 as an error code; how that code is interpreted depends on what function returned it.

Comment: But when you have an access violation they call it so, not error 31973616. And when you have a range check error they also call it so instead of 59283782.

Comment: @Beno: You're confusing exceptions and error codes; they're not the same thing. The function returns a **numeric value** that has a purpose. For instance, many API calls return 0 on success, and an error code. Others return FALSE, and you call GetLastError() (which returns a **numeric error code**) to find out why it failed. An access violation always means the same thing. A return code can mean any number of things, based on the function documentation and the return value, and there can't be a set name. Two functions can return 1785 and they can have totally different things.

Comment: (continued) Error code 1785 actually has multiple meanings. When dealing with SQL, error code 1785 means *introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'x' on table 'y' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths*. When dealing with backups, it means *EFS_DIR_MULTISTR_ERROR A temp backup file for '%s' cannot be created*. Since you're using neither of those, and based on the context, the one from winerror.h (*ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_MEDIA*) is the one that applies here.

Comment: The error codes are documented https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @KenWhite-So, my program called and API function which failed and this is why I see the 1785 message...

Comment: @Beno: Something in the code (whether yours or part of the Delphi RTL) called an API function that returned 1785 as a result, and that result was not a success code. I've explained that several times now; I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: You are all right: The code can be looked up to get the textual representation. But this lookup should be done by the code itself. This exception is generated by `System.SysUtils.CreateInOutError` and it maps only 7 codes to hardcoded resourcestrings. All other codes are just named as this common `EInOutError` message text. This should be done better by Emba

Comment: @Beno: And what good woutd UNRECOGNIZED have done? What more information would that have provided you than 1785 does? UNRECOGNIZED  gives you no information that can even be looked up, while 1785 does (using SysErrorMessage). I've given you the information you need, and you're still complaining about the way the WinAPI was designed and has worked for several decades instead of using it. Stop complaining and learn: if you read the API documentation at MSDN, you'll find that most API calls work exactly like this, and you can't predict the myriad of errors that will happen and sugar coat them.

Comment: To be fair to Emba, this control has been deprecated for around 15 years and it's wrong to expect it to change ever.